# How to Customize Vaadin 24 Dark Theme to Black Instead of Dark Blue?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am currently working on a Vaadin 24 project and I am looking to apply a dark theme to my app. The default dark theme provided by Vaadin is dark blue, but I am interested in changing it to black. I have looked through the Vaadin documentation but couldn't find a straightforward way to customize the color scheme of the dark theme.

Is there a way to alter the default dark theme color from dark blue to black in Vaadin 24? Has anyone done this before and could provide some guidance or code snippets on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  It's unclear, which
part is not working.  Changing the colors of the dark theme?  Can you
not make if fully black? ...

Comment: Please excuse my clumsy question. I am not sure what is the best approach to use the dark theme in my app. Do I really need to create and style a completely new theme, or is there possibly an add-on or something like that? It seems to me that this problem could affect many users.

Comment: See https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/lumo/lumo-style-properties/color

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is already a ready-made CSS style for a dark theme? I don't mean the built-in "blue" dark theme. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some usefull themes at the Vaadin Add-On Directory:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/breeze-theme-for-vaadin/1.0.5

Answer (score 1):

For those who may view this question and want to write a custom theme, they should read https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/application-theme. It covers how to create and apply a custom theme in Vaadin. Section [Master Stylesheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/application-theme#master-stylesheet) demonstrates how to override Lumo properties. Here's an example taken from the Breeze theme.

```css
[theme~="dark"] {
    --lumo-base-color: hsl(220, 15%, 15%);
    --lumo-shade-5pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.05);
    --lumo-shade-10pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.1);
    --lumo-shade-20pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.2);
    --lumo-shade-30pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.3);
    --lumo-shade-40pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.4);
    --lumo-shade-50pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.5);
    --lumo-shade-60pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.6);
    --lumo-shade-70pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.7);
    --lumo-shade-80pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.8);
    --lumo-shade-90pct: rgba(54, 61, 73, 0.9);
    --lumo-shade: hsl(220, 15%, 25%);
}
```

When I create a custom theme, I like to generate my colors. Here are some examples:

- https://lsparagino.medium.com/sass-only-material-angular-palette-generator-35dd406a6b81
- https://gist.github.com/brlodi/e18ce2947664aacbbd9186d24608ff7a
- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-build-color-palettes/
- https://gist.github.com/SimonPadbury/e0f081400e1c59487a806ea601067ba4